# Rails: One_to_one relationship and form_for sending format instead of ID and params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

I'm pretty new to rails and I'm having a bit of a though time to register my employeur.

Here are my routes:

```
  resources :users do
  resource :prestataire
  resource :employeur
  end
```

I have a has_one relationship between my employeur and user resources:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :prestataire
  has_one :employeur
  has_secure_password
end

class Employeur < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :siren, :societe, :code_postal, presence: true
end
```

And here's where I think the issue is:

```
<%= form_for [@user,@employeur], url: user_employeur_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @employeur.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@employeur.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this employeur from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @employeur.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :siren, 'Siren: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :siren %>
  </div>
.
.
.
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I fill in this issue, I'm redirected to /users/193/employeur.84 and I get this error: Couldn't find Employeur without an ID

Those are the only two params that are send after the form, even though I've indicated :siren, :societe, :code_postal
{"user_id"=>"193",
 "format"=>"84"}

I guess that this might also come from my Emmployeur controller:

```
class EmployeursController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user

  def index
    @employeurs = @user.employeur.all
  end


  def show
    @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id]) #This is where the error happens since no id is sent.
  end

  def new
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur
  end

  def edit
    @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur(employeur_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
  @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.update_attributes(employeur_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employeur }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def destroy
  @employeur = Employeur.find(params[:id])
  @employeur.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def employeur_params
    params.require(:employeur).permit(:siren, :societe, :code_postal)
  end

end
```

Any help would be more then welcome.

---

In order to give an example of singular and nested resource working, I'll add a little more of my code:

```
class Employeur < ActiveRecord::Base
  model_name.instance_variable_set(:@route_key, 'employeur')
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projets, as: :projetable
  has_many :prestataires, through: :projets
  has_many :offres, through: :projets
  has_many :feedbacks, through: :projets
  validates :siren, :societe, :code_postal, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :code_postal, presence: true
  validates_associated :user
end
```

Here's mu User controller that leads me from the user form to the employeur once filled:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

#TODO index user doit être suprimé quand inutile pour dev
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        if params[:commit] == 'Employeur'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations d'employeur" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: "Renseignez vos informations de prestataire" }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        if params[:commit] == 'Prestataire'
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_prestataire_path(user_id: @user), notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        else 
        format.html { redirect_to new_user_employeur_path(user_id: @user), notice: "User was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :surname, :forename, :civility, :phone)
  end

end
```

And finally, my User form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :civility, 'Titre de civilité: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :civility %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :forename, 'Prénom: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :forename %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :surname, 'Nom de famille: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :surname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email, 'Email: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, 'Mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirmation de mot de passe: ' %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone, 'Numéro de téléphone: ' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Employeur" %>
    <%= f.submit "Prestataire" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Hope this will help someone as much as it would have helped me. Cheers !

Comment: Try `user_employeur_path(@user, @employeur)` as the url for `form_for`.  Although, it might generate that same url by default anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have your `EmployeursController` setup correctly. Since `employeur` is a singular resource, you cannot reference it by id. Instead you need to change your `show` action to this:

```
def show
  @employeur = User.find(params[:user_id]).employeur
end
```

The reason is that `user_employeur_path(@user)` creates a path like `/users/193/employeur` where you can access the user id in the controller via `params[:user_id]`

Also, since `employeur` is a singular resource, there is no `index` action defined for it. You can remove the `index` action entirely from your controller.

Comment: Hamed, I'll only be able to test this in 4 hours. But anyway, and already, thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: ..... It worked :O ... This was the one thing I couldn't find anywhere !!! I was desperate and was about to quit rails. Hamed, thank you very much !!! You really made someone happy today. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing in the `@employeur` to your nested route `user_employeur_path`. Try this on your `form_for` line:

`user_employeur_path(@user, @employeur)`

But you shouldn't have to specify url; this should work:

```
<%= form_for [@user,@employeur] do |f| %>
```

See [creating paths and urls from objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#creating-paths-and-urls-from-objects).

Comment: and Max Williams, this would work for has_many relationships, but is a real rails issue with has_one as indicated here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1769.

Comment: I've been able to test it, and it doesn't work, neither with user_employeur_path(@user, @employeur), nor <%= form_for [@user,@employeur] do |f| %>.

Comment: Damien Roche, there's a rails problem that prevents this solution to work with singular resources... Yet, if you had to your model :   model_name.instance_variable_set(:@route_key, 'employeur')  AND adapt 'employeur' to the name of your resource, your suggestion will work. Yet, my error didn't come from there. Anyway, thanks a lot for helping me with this hard issue.

Comment: That's a shame @Francky. Glad you got it sorted, anyway. +1 for submitting the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

For people like me who were desperate to find an example of nested and singular resource working, I post my controller corrected thanks to the help of Hamed:

```
class EmployeursController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user

  def new
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur
  end

  def show
  @employeur = @user.employeur
  end


  def edit
    @employeur = @user.employeur
  end


  def create
    @employeur = @user.build_employeur(employeur_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
  @employeur = @user.employeur
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employeur.update_attributes(employeur_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@user, @employeur], notice: 'Employeur was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employeur }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employeur.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


def destroy
  @employeur = @user.employeur
  @employeur.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end

private
  def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def employeur_params
    params.require(:employeur).permit(:siren, :societe, :code_postal)
  end

end
```